# Formula for data that looks like a hockey stick

Tags: java, math

The following are X and Y values:

```
X    Y
20   10
100  25
140  50
```

It would be nice if I could approximately represent this data as a formula and plug in any arbitrary value of X from 20 to 140. The data seems to be kind of like a hockey stick curve. Or is it more exponential? I could code this to just create linear segments between those three points but it would be way better if a formula could give me more of a smooth result. The numbers above aren't fixed in stone. They can vary a little. As long as the formula gets me in the ballpark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the equation of a polynomial or an exponential to approximate that kind of shape, which one you pick sort of depends on what exactly you are trying to do.

If you just need a smooth curve that is close to some shape, then pick a formula and tweak the coefficients until it looks how you want.

A polynomial fit of your data from Excel gives:

```
Y = 0.0036*(X^2) - 0.25*X + 13.542
```

Comment: @AndroidDev Glad to see that you like my second-order polynomial, after all.

Answer (score 1):

Three points uniquely define a second-order polynomial curve, of the form

y = Ax<sup>2</sup> + Bx + C

There are widely known formulas to deduce A, B, C from the point coordinates.

Comment: I don't have a formula. That's what I am looking for. I also did not define the data as parabolic or any other. However, those 3 points should approximate what the curve looks like.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik - after a bit more thought, I stand corrected, and have deleted my comments.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is by implementing some [GROWTH](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/growth-function-HA102753003.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA102752955) function similar to the one offered by Excel. It will interpolate a `new_y` value from a `new_x` value you give it, assuming some exponential growth. Here is a piece of code for it in JavaScript. Translating it to Java should be pretty straightforward.

Note that I borrowed most of it from someone else (credits in the code).

```
function GROWTH(known_y, known_x, new_x, use_const) {
  // Credits: Ilmari Karonen

  // Default values for optional parameters:
  if (typeof(known_x) == 'undefined') {
    known_x = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= known_y.length; i++) known_x.push(i);
  }
  if (typeof(new_x) == 'undefined') {
    new_x = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= known_y.length; i++) new_x.push(i);
  }
  if (typeof(use_const) == 'undefined') use_const = true;

  // Calculate sums over the data:
  var n = known_y.length;
  var avg_x = 0;
  var avg_y = 0;
  var avg_xy = 0;
  var avg_xx = 0; 
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var x = known_x[i];
    var y = Math.log(known_y[i]);
    avg_x += x;
    avg_y += y;
    avg_xy += x*y;
    avg_xx += x*x;
  }
  avg_x /= n;
  avg_y /= n;
  avg_xy /= n;
  avg_xx /= n;

  // Compute linear regression coefficients:
  if (use_const) {
    var beta = (avg_xy - avg_x*avg_y) / (avg_xx - avg_x*avg_x);
    var alpha = avg_y - beta*avg_x;
  } else {
    var beta = avg_xy / avg_xx;
    var alpha = 0;
  }

  // Compute and return result array:
  var new_y = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < new_x.length; i++) {
    new_y.push(Math.exp(alpha + beta * new_x[i]));
  }
  return new_y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can statistically fit a curve to a set of points using some form of [regression analyzis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis). However, the validity of your curve depends on the number of points that you have; three points do not give a lot of confidence that your formula is correct.

Answer (score -1):

You can start by assuming a relationship like this:

```
y = A*exp(B*x)
```

Taking the natural log of both sides:

```
ln(y) = ln(A) + B*x
```

Substitute as many points as you like and solve for the two coefficients.  It's a simple linear regression problem.

Here's what I get for your data:

```
y = exp(2.006369+0.013132*x)
```

Here's a table of generated values:

```
X   Y
0   7.436267437
20  9.669855877
40  12.5743343
60  16.35121402
80  21.26253316
100 27.6490367
120 35.95381719
140 46.75305634
160 60.7960002
180 79.0569415
200 102.8028156
220 133.6811
240 173.8341152
260 226.0476583
```

This will work even if you have lots of data.

If you do a Taylor series expansion of the exponential function, you'll see that it's an infinite series of polynomial terms.  The quadratic and cubic proposals are truncated approximations to the exponential.

Comment: The quadratic and cubic proposals are **not** the truncated approximations to the exponential. For example, my proposal is not an approximation at all, it is an **exact solution**.

Comment: I'm not commenting on your solution per se; I'm only saying that a quadratic or cubic solution can be viewed as stopping the infinite Taylor series for an exponential at terms 2 and 3.   Nothing more.  No need for bold text or getting your back up.

Comment: But you are stating a falsehood: `y = A*exp(B*x)` **cannot be solved** for three arbitrary points---as opposed to `y = Ax^2 + Bx + C`.

Comment: I'm not stating a falsehood - you don't know Taylor series, and you don't understand my point.  Stop thinking about my comment in terms of your solution.  I never said it could be solved for three arbitrary coefficients.  Look at my solution: I only have two.

Comment: You said "the quadratic and cubic proposals are truncated approximations to the exponential" That statement is a blatant falsity. How can an exact fit be an approximation of an approximation? You are clearly mixing up the general Taylor series with the Taylor expansion of the exponential.

Comment: If I take the Taylor series of the exponential, and stop at the second order term, I have a quadratic.  If I stop at the third order term, I have a cubic.  If I keep adding terms, I get the full exponential.  That is all I'm saying.  I might have worded it poorly, or you just might not understand it.  In either case, I have no idea why you're so exercised about it.  The general Taylor series isn't all that helpful until I identify which function I'm expanding - in this case, the exponential.  I certainly do know the difference.  I'll put my math background up against yours any day.

Comment: What you don't have is a **general** second-order polynomial, and that is what the "proposals" you mention are. They could also be looked at as the partial sums of some general Taylor series, but only a few very constrained special cases will match the Taylor expansion of an exponential function.